# How can an argument increment without being explicitly told to do so?

Tags: javascript, function, higher-order-functions

In the following `function` why does "i" argument `increment`?

```
function colWidths(rows) {
      return rows[0].map(function(_, i) {
        return rows.reduce(function(max, row) {
          return Math.max(max, row[i].minWidth());
        }, 0);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Because `map` passes it to the callback function and can make it any value it wants…!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function passed to map is just called with different values of i. You can write your own `simplified` version of the map function like so:

```
function map(arr, callback){
  let newArr = []
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    newArr.push(callback(arr[i], i));
  }
  return newArr;
}

mapped = map(["Zero", "One", "Two"], function(el, i){ return i });
console.log(mapped)
```

Comment: That's `forEach`, not `map`.

Comment: Oops. Updated. Thanks.

Comment: If I may tack on an additional question: How can I identify the value of an argument belonging to a function located within another functions when it is not explicitly passed? E.g. How do you know "i" is a callback function.

Comment: Are you talking about where you wrote `Math.max(max, row[i].minWidth());`? It's not passed on but rather calling a function creates a scope and any code inside that function has access to variables within that scope. Here's a pretty intense article about scope, I believe it will have the answer you're looking for: https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Comment: this should be posted as comments not answer.